# Inverse injective type families

Tags: haskell, type-families

Lets say I have an injective type family `T`

```
type family T a = b | b -> a
```

My first question is there an way to write:

```
type family T' = the inverse of T
```

Without having to repeat all the instances of `T` but in reverse.

Such that: `T (X1 a (T' a)) = a`

It seems like this should work, as both `T` and `T'` are injective, given one side it is mechanical to work out the other.

Anyway to write `T'`?

Comment: Wouldn't `a ~ T b` work ?

Comment: Apparently `type Tinv b = a` is rejected because the tyvar `a` must be mentioned in the arguments of `Tinv`, which looks too restrictive when it is determined by them thanks to the fundeps in scope.

Comment: It is impossible to convert the fundep to an explicit type family application, but as @mb14 said, using an equality constraint in a type signature you can compute the inverse - e.g. `(a ~ T b) => Proxy a -> Proxy b` or equivalently `Proxy (T b) -> Proxy b`.

Comment: Injective type families smell like a language feature in progress. Their restrictions (such as not allowing any type family applications in the RHS) are extremely unnatural.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With suitable extensions, one can write:

```
type T' b = forall a. T a ~ b => a
```

For example, here's an example showing that you get at least basic type compatibility with this type synonym:

```
type family T a = b | b -> a
type instance T Int = Bool

f :: T' Bool -> Int
f x = x
```

Comment: Is there any way to write the inverse function of `f`: `g :: Int -> T' Bool`? My guess is no?

Comment: @Hjulle Huh. Seems like a bug. You should report it to the GHC issue tracker and see what they say.